# what is an example of a data structure?

Tags: java, algorithm, data-structures

I have this algorithm assignment where it ask us to design a data structure? we haven't learn a topic about data structure so I don't know what data structure looks like. Is it like pseudo code or something? can someone show me an example.

Here is my assignment: https://i.stack.imgur.com/kgJpm.jpg

Comment: google is useful , always use it

Comment: This seems like a fairly advanced question if you don't even know what a data structure is. I suggest that you read your textbooks - there is too much material to cover for a single question.

Comment: @user3529245 - Stack Overflow works best when you have specific programming problems. The idea is you ask a specific question, and you get an assortment of answers that covers various aspects of the answer (sometimes, you get a great answer that covers nearly all aspects). You should not ask others to find you examples or tutorials. You're expected to find that on your own. See [How do I ask a good question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [How do I ask and answer homework questions?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/10811/how-do-i-ask-and-answer-homework-questions).

Answer (score 1):

An example of data structure is:

```
struct exampleStructure {
    int thisIsFieldOne;
    string thisIsAnotherField;
    long yetAnotherOne;
}
```

So basically it is a "set" of data, usually created to represent something. For example:

```
struct point {
   int xCoordinate;
   int yCoordinate
}
```

Data structure can have some special abilities, like keeping its elements in a specified order (BST Trees) or allowing access in constant time (hash tables). You can read more on Wikipedia, for example: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_structure

It may be also OK to create a class containing specific fields (representing data you want your structure to represent) and providing special methods for manipulating those fields, so that they provide desired behaviour. For example:

```
class SortedSet {
    private List<int> list;

    public void insert(int x) {
        //code to insert x at the right position, so that list is sorter
    }
}
```

The class above is of course very simplified, but I believe it is enough for a start. Remember: class is not the same as data structure (it is a bigger concept, I'd say), but you can make your class act like a data structure.

Comment: Would probably be more helpful if this was in Java.

Comment: I see your point, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Examples of data structures:

[Queue](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Queue_%28abstract_data_type%29) , [Stack](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stack_%28abstract_data_type%29) etc...

There many more complex data tructures like search trees and hash tables.